# Test roles access to controllers in symfony

Tags: symfony, unit-testing, phpunit, roles

I'm asking myself how to tests with phpunit in symfony roles access.
For example, if i have an indexAction and 5 different roles in my security config, i want to be sure that user A will have a 401, user B a 403, user C a 500...

But it cause an issue: tests are really long to execute, because we have 5 functional tests by action.

Now, i'm doing that kind of thing:

```
/**
 * @covers \App\Bundle\FrontBundle\Controller\DefaultController::indexAction()
 *
 * @dataProvider rolesAllAccess
 *
 * @param string  $user
 * @param integer $expectedCode
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function testRolesIndexAction($user, $expectedCode)
{
    $client = $this->createClientWith($user);
    $client->request('GET', '/');

    $this->assertEquals($expectedCode, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
}
```

The function createClientWith authenticate a client that i have defined in my dataProvider before. It makes exactly what i described before.

Do you have any idea on how doing that better or - at least - with better performances ?

Thanks!

Comment: You could execute your tests asynchronously / in parallel to speed up the overall execution time.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your authentication method. I use JWT. Also, all my web tests extends ApiTestCase that extends WebTestCase. And In all WebTestCases I use a logged user. Logged use log in inside the setup method.

```
abstract class ApiTestCase extends WebTestCase
{
    protected function setUp()
    {
        $client = static::makeClient();

        $client->request(
            'POST',
            '/tokens', [
                'username' => 'username',
                'password' => 'password'
            ], [
                // no files here
            ],
            $headers = [
                'HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'HTTP_ACCEPT' => 'application/json',
            ]
        );

        $response = $client->getResponse();

        $data = json_decode($response->getContent(), true);

        $this->client = static::createClient(
            array(),
            array(
                'HTTP_Authorization' => sprintf('%s %s', 'Bearer', $data['token']),
                'HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json',
                'HTTP_ACCEPT'       => 'application/json',
            )
        );
    }
}
```

And here an example of test:

```
class DivisionControllerTest extends ApiTestCase
{
    public function testList()
    {
        $this->client->request('GET', '/resource');

        $response = $this->client->getResponse();
        $expectedContent = ' !!! put expected content here !!! ';

        $this->assertEquals(
            $expectedContent,
            $response->getContent()
        );
    }
}
```

Your test could be

```
public function testRolesIndexAction($expectedCode)
{
    $this->client->request('GET', '/');

    $this->assertEquals($expectedCode, $this->client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [this](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/fixtures.html#fixtures.more-setup-than-teardown) to call one time $this->createClientWith. I suggest to look [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/http_authentication.html) for more recommandation.